# CSS - Fixed button on expanding

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

I am trying to make the search bar expand on device size < 768px. [GIF Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyhkO.gif).
How to fixed button when I click expand?

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-search {
    margin-left: 1em;

    .search-bar {
      max-width: 3em;
      margin-left: auto;
      
      &:focus-within {
        max-width: 100%;
        
        .search-bar__input {
          width: auto;
          padding: 0 1em;
        }
      }
    }

    .search-bar__input {
      width: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my codepen:
https://codepen.io/phamtien990819/pen/PoqGwEv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest remove the line `width:auto` in `&:focus-within .search-bar__input`.
Moreover, you can add padding transition to `.search-bar__input` to make the transition smoother

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-search {
    margin-left: 1em;

    .search-bar {
      max-width: 3em;
      margin-left: auto;

      &:focus-within {
        max-width: 100%;

        .search-bar__input {
          /*Remove width: auto*/
          padding: 0 1em;
        }
      }
    }

    .search-bar__input {
      width: 0;
      padding: 0;

      /*Add padding transition*/
      transition: padding 3s
    }

    .search-bar__btn { }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This CSS code I updated. I used `position: absolute;` to place button on right of the bar. So even after input is opened button stays on right without moving.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-search {
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: relative;
    .search-bar__input {
      margin-left: 10px;
      background: transparent;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .search-bar__btn {
      width: 40px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 1px;
      height: 29px;
    }
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ol,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}

.material-icons {
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.material-icons::before {
  content: attr(icon);
}

.site-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: -40px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.top-nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.top-nav .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
}

.top-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
  list-style: none;
}

.top-nav ul>li+li {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.top-nav ul a {
  color: currentColor;
}

.main-nav .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5em;
}

.header-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-brand .logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: currentColor;
}

.header-brand .menu-toggle {
  display: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 1em;
  padding: 6px;
}


/* BEGIN SEARCH BAR */

.header-search {
  flex: auto;
  margin-left: 4em;
}

.header-search .search-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 25em;
  height: 2.5em;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.header-search .search-bar__input {
  flex: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  outline: 0;
}

.header-search .search-bar__btn {
  width: 3em;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-search {
    margin-left: 1em;
    position: relative;
  }
  .header-search .search-bar__input {
    margin-left: 10px;
    background: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header-search .search-bar__btn {
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
    height: 29px;
  }
  .header-search .search-bar {
    max-width: 3em;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  .header-search .search-bar:focus-within {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .header-search .search-bar:focus-within .search-bar__input {
    width: auto;
  }
  .header-search .search-bar__input {
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}


/* END SEARCH BAR */

.header-user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-user .item {
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header-user .item .user-link {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: currentColor;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.header-user .item .user-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .s-header {
    top: 0;
  }
  .top-nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-nav .container {
    height: 4em;
  }
  .header-brand .menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <header class="site-header">
    <div class="top-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Top menu item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Top menu item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Top menu item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Top menu item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Top menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header-brand">
          <a class="logo d-none d-md-inline-block" href="#">LOGO HERE</a>
          <button class="menu-toggle">
                        <i class="material-icons" icon="menu"></i>
                    </button>
        </div>
        <div class="header-search">
          <form action="#" class="search-bar">
            <input class="search-bar__input" type="search" placeholder="Search..." />
            <button class="search-bar__btn" type="button">
                            <i class="material-icons" icon="search"></i>
                        </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="header-user">
          <li class="item">
            <a class="user-link" href="#">
              <i class="material-icons" icon="person_add"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Login / Register</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container" style="height: 1000px">
      <p class="mt-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Footer content</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```